# Getting the images from multiupload field in order of their adding

Tags: javascript, html

Is there is any way to get images from HTML multiupload file field in the order they have been added (clicked)?

Comment: No there isn't, you get a fileList with the files and that's it.

Comment: Please put your comment as answer as seems correct and would like to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File API makes it possible to access a [**FileList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) containing File objects representing the files selected by the user.

A fileList is an array-like object, and when multiple files have been selected by the user the returned fileList contains all the files.

The order of the files in the fileList seems to be generally up the browser to decide, and the files are not put in the fileList in the same order as the user selected them.